# How can I show the forums sent by the visitor from different sites in a single panel or in one place?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

I have 4 different sites with WordPress infrastructure. I want to ensure that the forums sent by the visitor from the contact form on my 4 different sites are displayed on a single panel. The contact form I am using shows up in the wordpress admin panel without setting the forminator smtp. It's hard to go to 4 different sites every day to check the forums, get into the admin panel. I want to make my job easier to see all forum information from visitors from different sites in one place. How can I do that

Can you give your opinion on this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the plugin you are using, but maybe webhooks are a good way to handle this data on a single panel.
At each form's submission, the plugin will send the form data to a specific endpoint. After that, you simply need to store these entries in a db for example.